# A clear question made unclear by OP's comment

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, needs-more-focus

[SVG Path Data Regex C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340156/svg-path-data-regex-c-sharp) is a question that was put on hold as **to broad**, which suprised me as I believed to understand it clearly, and gave a simple answer.

What I now believe what happened is that a commenter asked "What are you trying to accomplish?", because he suspected the method the OP asked about would not be appropriate.

The OP's answer to that comment (another comment, not an edit to the question) is completely unclear and may even expose some false assumptions on his side about the the data format he is trying to parse.

The OP asked about what amounts to a *lexer* (returning a sequence of tokens), even if he didn't use that term. The comment was about what you would do with *parsed* (syntactically analyzed) data. RegEx for a parser is certainly a broad and potentially un-answerable question. But he didn't ask that. Designing a lexer is not a case of "square wheels" (clear, but stupid), I'd say.

So, if a OP is throwing mud into the water in a comment, is that a reason to close an initially (mostly) clear question?

Comment: Even if that first comment wasn't there, I'd dare say that it would have been closed anyway. Without a concrete attempt, the question looks like yet another "plz give regex", which are generally not a good idea for this site.

Comment: So if he had posted what he characterized as "my hacked together regex", it would have been legit?

Comment: Any comment that elaborates on what the OP wants should be added to the question itself. If the comment is something that should be edited into the question then it should be considered as far as whether the question is clear.